# zlib module not playing nicely with web deployment

Tags: heroku, trigger.io

Trying to deploy to heroku, seems like the zlib module isn't playing nicely. Any ideas?

```
2012-08-16T20:50:07+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web.js`
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]: node.js:134
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'zlib'
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:348:19)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js:14:12)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:348:19)
2012-08-16T20:50:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.compress (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:89:14)
2012-08-16T20:50:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-16T20:50:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out express got rid of its zlib dependency, so you have to add zlib (version "1.0") to package.json under /development/web

**Update:** this is fixed in v1.4.11

Comment: Thanks Chris, we'll report back here when the issue is fixed so you don't need to do this manual workaround

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in v1.4.11 of the Forge platform: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-11

Thanks for reporting!